# HTML/CSS - Search Form

Tags: html, css

[image: booking form]

I need something like this for a site web,but 
I do not know how to make a form like this which contain all 3 joins in one form. Everything must be done in HTML and CSS, without using javascript.

Some advice?

Comment: Simply Google it

Answer (score 0):

Float css property can help you to display your input as you want inside a main div.

```css
input {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input value="text" style="width:100px" type="text"/>
    <input value="date" style="width:100px" type="date"/>
    <input value="text" style="width:100px" type="text"/>
    <input value="button" style="width:100px" type="button"/>
</div>
```